# Kivy Vertex Instruction Ordering

Tags: python, kivy

In kivy,how do I specify the order in which something is drawn? I'm trying to have a line I drew show up in front of my other objects. This is what is in the canvas right now:

```
[<kivy.graphics.instructions.Canvas object at 0x1115155a8>, 
<kivy.graphics.instructions.Canvas object at 0x111565a68>, 
<kivy.graphics.instructions.Canvas object at 0x1115aeb00>, 
<kivy.graphics.instructions.Canvas object at 0x111712df8>,
<kivy.graphics.context_instructions.BindTexture object at 0x111511770>, 
<kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions.Line object at 0x105f0d3b0>]
```

Do I need to move the order of the instruction to make the line be the object on top?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the order of drawing is the order that instructions appear on the canvas.